# Не удается создать работающий интерфейс с подбором подходящих версии cplex м python! У кого есть такой опыт?

Tags: python

Не удается создать работающий интерфейс с подбором 
 подходящих версии cplex м python! У кого есть такой опыт?

Выполняя команду 
 "python setup.py install" 
 для создания интерфейса (модуля cplex) между python и cplex
 я получаю сообщение
 <<
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 36, in 
     raise Exception(ERROR_STRING)
 Exception: CPLEX 12.7.0.0 is not compatible with this version of Python.

> >
>    Есть ли успешный опыт создания работающего интерфейса с подбором 
>    подходящих версии cplex м python!